# Flutter: Using navigation functionalities for named routes with MaterialPageRoute without named routes

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have seen many navigation functionalities using named routes like popAndPushNamed,popUntil,pushNamedAndRemoveUntil,pushReplacementNamed. I want to know how to use these functionalities with MaterialPageRoute where i dont have my routes named.
For example:
i have a pages
Screen 1 
Screen 2
Screen 3 
Screen 4
so from Screen 4 i want to popUntil Screen 2 without using names.
i have read posts where i you can name these routes while pushing but i have issues with that because i have to pass arguments and so i want to just use the functionalities wihtout naming my routes. I am a learner so please take it easy on me.

`Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/Page1"));`

basically i want to do the above and other functionalities for named routes without using named routes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to go from screen 4-->to screen 3--> and stay at screen 2. So this means you need 2 pops, hence do it like this:

```
count = 0;
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
return count++ == 2;
});
```